# SQL to find atleast one not nulls in multiple columns

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with few non key attributes. I would like to know how can I write a query to find the key columns where I can find not nulls in any one row of these.

For example 1:

```
Key1 Key2 NonKey1 NonKey2    
k1   k2   nk1      nk2    
k1   k2   null     nk2    
k1   k2   nk1      null
```

For example 2:

```
Key1 Key2 NonKey1 NonKey2 NonKey3    
k1   k2   null     nk2     nk3
k1   k2   nk1      nk2     null
```

Expected:

```
Key1 Key2 NonKey1 NonKey2
k1   k2   nk1      nk2
```

Comment: I might not be having not nulls in the same row, so if I do 'and' it might not work. I might have not null for nonkey1 in first row and for nonkey2 it might be in second row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    select key1, key2, max(nonkey2), max(nonkey3)
    from MyTable
    having max(nonkey2) is not null or max(nonkey3) is not null
    group by key1, key2
```

(This is SQL Server, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you simply want to grab one value per non-key column?

```
select key1, key2, max(nonkey1), max(nonkey2)
from mytable
group by key1, key2;
```

Answer (score 0):

other method:

```
select distinct key1, key2
from MyTable
where nonkey2 is not null and nonkey3 is not null
```